# Filter text based in a multiline match criteria

Tags: sed, awk

I have the following sed command. I need to execute the below command in single line

```
cat File | sed -n '      
/NetworkName/ {
N
/\n.*ims3/ p
}' | sed -n 1p | awk -F"=" '{print $2}'
```

I need to execute the above command in single line. can anyone please help.

Assume that the contents of the File is

```
System.DomainName=shayam
System.Addresses=Fr6
System.Trusted=Yes
System.Infrastructure=No
System.NetworkName=AS
System.DomainName=ims5.com
System.DomainName=Ram
System.Addresses=Fr9
System.Trusted=Yes
System.Infrastructure=No
System.NetworkName=Peer
System.DomainName=ims7.com
System.DomainName=mani
System.Addresses=Hello
System.Trusted=Yes
System.Infrastructure=No
System.NetworkName=Peer
System.DomainName=ims3.com
```

And after executing the command you will get only peer as the output. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: If you are looking for just "Peer", this is way simpler:

    "cat File | grep Peer"

to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single nawk command. And you can lost the useless cat

```
nawk -F"=" '/NetworkName/{n=$2;getline;if($2~/ims3/){print n} }' file
```

You can use sed as well as proposed by others, but i prefer less regex and less clutter.
The above save the value of the network name to "n". Then, get the next line and check the 2nd field against "ims3". If matched, then print the value of "n".

Comment: This may be a bit clearer: `nawk -F= '/NetworkName/ {name=$2} $2~/ims3/ {print name}'`

Answer (score 1):

Put that code in a separate `.sh` file, and run it as your single-line command.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want the network name where the domain name on the following line includes 'ims3', and not the one where the following line includes 'ims7' (even though the network names in the example are the same).

```
sed -n '/NetworkName/{N;/ims3/{s/.*NetworkName=\(.*\)\n.*/\1/p;};}' File
```

This avoids abuse of felines, too (not to mention reducing the number of commands executed).

Tested on MacOS X 10.6.4, but <s>there's no reason to think it won't work elsewhere too</s>.

---

However, empirical evidence shows that Solaris `sed` is different from MacOS `sed`.  It can all be done in one `sed` command, but it needs three lines:

```
sed -n '/NetworkName/{N
/ims3/{s/.*NetworkName=\(.*\)\n.*/\1/p;}
}' File
```

Tested on Solaris 10.

Comment: Hi.
 I just pasted this in solaris machine. it is not working. Too many {' is the error i am getting.. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
cat File | sed -n '/NetworkName/ { N; /\n.*ims3/ p }' | sed -n 1p | awk -F"=" '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Abuse of felines?  And it can all be done with a single '`sed`' command.

Comment: He wanted to know how to write the command that he got already working on one line. I showed him where to place the semicolon.

Comment: The following is the error i am getting. 
sed: command garbled: /NetworkName/ { N; /\n.*ims3/ p }

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the network name for the domain **ims3**, this command line works without *sed*:

```
grep -B 1 ims3 File | head -n 1 | awk -F"=" '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put `-e` pretty much everywhere you'd break the command at a newline or have a semicolon. You don't need the extra call to `sed` or `awk` or `cat`.

```
sed -n -e '/NetworkName/ {' -e 'N' -e '/\n.*ims3/ s/[^\n]*=\(.*\).*/\1/P' -e '}' File
```